# SQL CASE statement WHEN and THEN values from SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am not sure if this question already has answers on SO, but as I couldn't find one, I am writing here. I am trying to write an update query using CASE statement. The values of `WHEN` and `THEN` comes from user-given data where I need to update multiple rows with multiple values that the user gives. I am eliminating the loop that I have written in the original code in the snippet below as the problem is only with `AddWithValue`. Is there a way to use `SqlParameterCollection` to assign the `THEN` value? Or is a simple string concatenation a way to do this?

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Table] SET Column = CASE ", connection);
command.CommandText += "WHEN Column = @Column1 THEN @Column2";
command.CommandText += "ELSE Column END";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", "Value1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", "Value2");
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@Column2'

Comment: You're missing an `END;` clause (after the `THEN @Column2`) for your `CASE` expression

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, just updated the snippet.

Comment: Also - you should **NOT** use `AddWithValue` - it has its share of problems. Use an approach that clearly and explicitly defines the datatype of the parameter, and length/precision settings. Furthermore: your first `AddWithValue` uses `"@Column1 "` with an extra, unnecessary space - avoid that!

Comment: Did you run SQL Profiler to check the actual sql statement that is being executed? Why not frame the entire sql command upfront and pass it to SqlCommand constructor?

Comment: ..@Column2ELSE.. - add a space.

Comment: @anandsowmithiran, As I have mentioned in my question the CASE statements are dynamic. There can be 'n' number of WHEN and THEN statements. I used a for loop to frame them. But anyways, I've taken them all down and just sticked to that simple snippet shown above which too doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Diagnostic hint: *any* time you see "incorrect syntax" in a SQL statement, log the SQL statement and examine it. I suspect you'd have spotted the `@Column2ELSE` yourself if you'd done that. It's much easier to look at the actual SQL than try to guess what it will be by inspecting the code.

Comment: @jonskeet, I haven't spotted that because I haven't written that when I asked the question. After the first comment here, I added that part and then yeah, I was able to fix that part. It was at last an incomplete syntax of CASE statement - The last `ELSE Column END` was added after reading the comments. Thank you all :)

Comment: @Deepak: Right - what I'm suggesting is that *in future*, if you see something similar, the first thing to do is log the SQL.

Comment: Change the way your write queries. You should always avoid updating rows that do not need to be updated. The ELSE part of your CASE expression will assign the current value when the search expression returns FALSE. Rather than use CASE, filter your rows using a WHERE clause and remove the CASE. Think SMARTER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to note that this syntax error probably also wouldn't have occurred if you'd used verbatim strings:

```
    new SqlCommand(@"
UPDATE [Table] 
SET 
  Column = CASE 
    WHEN Column = @Column1 THEN @Column2 
    ELSE Column 
  END"
    , connection);
```

I tend to stick all the sql so it starts from indent level 0, and using the @ string means it can be formatted how I like an sql to be without any interim c# making it messy.

If you're building a variable number of cases, string interpolation might also tidy things up and you can have an interpolated @ string by prefixing `$@` - I remember which way round they go by "Microsoft are polite and didn't want to fill people's code with `@$` (ass)" ;)

```
var whens = "WHEN...";
for(...){
  whens += ...
  parameters.Add(..)
}

new SqlCommand($@"
UPDATE [Table] 
SET 
  Column = CASE 
    {whens}
    ELSE Column 
  END
", connection);
```

And of course final debugging tip; if you build an sql dynamically and you get a syntax error, pause in the debugger and look at the command text just before you run it; point to the Command variable, open the tooltip, click the magnifying glass next to CommandText property to see the string as is in a notepad style window, with new lines etc as actual new lines not as \n that the debug tooltip shows - it's a lot easier to spot syntax errors in this visualizer

[image]

<sub>image courtesy of https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-toquerystring/amp/</sub>

Answer (score 1):

So finally it's all about the syntax errors as mentioned by @marc_s and @serg in the comments. This worked:

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Table] SET Column = CASE ", connection);
command.CommandText += "WHEN Column = @Column1 THEN @Column2 ";
command.CommandText += "ELSE Column END";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", "Value1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", "Value2");
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Now just use `command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "Value1");` and I'd be happy :-)

Comment: Though note those concerns don't necessarily affect other DBs, and it wouldn't be so much of an issue with  stored procedures either. Do try to keep a "Don't use AddWithValue with SQLServer *queries*" mantra though

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL Server code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", "Value1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", "Value2");

String StrSqlCommand = "UPDATE [Table] SET Column = CASE ";
StrSqlCommand += " WHEN Column = @Column1 THEN @Column2 ";
StrSqlCommand += " ELSE Column END ";

command.CommandText = StrSqlCommand;    

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also be careful about the terms "Value1" and "Value2". Because in the code you send, the above values are considered exactly the same as the string type. If you want another value, it is better to define a variable and put it as a parameter in the above expressions. Something like this:

```
        String strValue1 = "Name1";
        String steValue2 = "Name2";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column1", strValue1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column2", strValue2);

        String StrSqlCommand = "UPDATE [Table] SET Column = CASE ";
        StrSqlCommand += " WHEN Column = @Column1 THEN @Column2 ";
        StrSqlCommand += " ELSE Column END ";

        command.CommandText = StrSqlCommand;

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited and I added a point to your post  @Caius Jard